# Entity not committed when expected (Hibernate ORM with Panache)

Tags: hibernate, quarkus

During the execution of a process I open two transactions:

- One to create an object and inform that the process has started;
- Another to change the object that was created in the first transaction, informing that the process was completed;

However, after executing the second transaction method, if I query the database the value has not yet been updated. What I expected is that after the execution of the method with the @transactional annotation is finished, the object is already committed to the database.

The reproduction of the situation is in the project:
https://github.com/emersonl91/quarkus-test

Important lines:
https://github.com/emersonl91/quarkus-tests/blob/master/code-with-quarkus/src/main/java/org/acme/MyService.java#L32

https://github.com/emersonl91/quarkus-tests/blob/master/code-with-quarkus/src/test/java/org/acme/ExampleResourceTest.java#L37

---

**Edit 1:** I tested the UserTransaction and TransactionManager classes, but the same problem also occurs.

---

**Edit 2:** In the transactionTest method I added the @transactional(NOT_SUPPORTED) annotation, in the persist and update methods I added the @transactional(REQUIRES_NEW) annotation. The result did not change.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you move `@Transactional` to the `transactionTest()` method?

Comment: The process runs successfully, but in a single transaction, not in 3 as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

The default transaction propagation level is REQUIRED. Thus, if one method (annotated with @Transactional) calls another method (annotated with @Transactional), the second method will use the existing transaction of the first method and not create a new one. In order to force a new transaction for the second method, you need to change the propagation level of the second method to REQUIRES_NEW. That said, I have never found a use case for that.

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation

Comment: I did this test:
1. In the transactionTest method I added the @Transactional(NOT_SUPPORTED) annotation;
2. In the persist and update methods I added the @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW) annotation ;

The result did not change..